# UINavigationBar appearance not always working

Tags: ios, uiappearance

I'm using this code at my AppDelegates `applicationDidFinishWorking` method:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor redColor],
                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor],
}];
```

This works for the first 2 UIViewControllers which are push to the UINavigationController. But at level 3 the title appears in it's standard colors (White, with grey shadow).

Has someone experienced similar problems?

Update:

- No Storyboard
- Im pushing the new UIViewControllers always like this:

  ```
  UIViewController *con = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  [navigationController pushViewController:con animated:YES];
  [con release];
  ```
- I've checked using custom 'init' method or not
- Tested also setting the title before or after pushing the UIViewController to the navigation stack

Comment: You use storyboard/xib or do everything in your code?

Comment: what you are doing at level3? not pushing?

Comment: Double check in the third view controller. Some code may change the attributes of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

try using images, I use images and works in all my Navigations.

UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"];
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];